# RaspberryPi mouse scrolling direction

Tags: mouse

I'm trying to set my raspberry pi to "Natural Scrolling" when accessing via VNC.  Have added the following in the first section /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf but it still scrolls the "unnatural" way.  Surprisingly, not a whole lot about this on the internet and would think it would(should!) be in the configuration set-up.

**Section "InputClass"
Identifier "libinput pointer catchall"
MatchIsPointer "on"
MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
Driver "libinput"
Option "NaturalScrolling" "true"          <------  Added line.
EndSection**

Comment: what's `natural` and `unnatural`?

Comment: AFAIK no Linux distribution (or anything else) has implemented this silly Apple idea.

Comment: Please explain to me why it's a "silly Idea".

Comment: I have been using microcomputers for almost 50 years and a mouse for 40. Apple suddenly decided what I was doing was "unnatural". What I find unnatural is having to switch habits when I use a different computer.

Comment: Incidentally I was trying to resolve a mouse problem, and discovered `xinput list-props 6` (where 6 is the id of my mouse) showed "libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled 0". You may be able to change with `libinput`

Comment: Dear @Milliways,  See [link](https://slate.com/technology/2011/09/apple-s-mousetrap-why-did-apple-reverse-the-way-we-scroll-up-and-down.html),  Think it gives a reasonable explanation. A lot of the links in it are broken.  Admittedly I prefer the “Natural” method but to call either “silly” is like saying “up” is “serious” and “down” is “silly”.  It’s just a matter of preference.  By the way, I’m 77 and my first computer was an Apple II in 1982 and have worked in IT/Telecomms isince 1987. Checked my version of Mac OS, you can change the direction by a simple button in the Settings.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @milliways last comment, I found the problem.  I didn't have X System running as I was using VNC for Remote Desktop.  As soon as I hooked up a VDU, keyboard & mouse, scrolling worked in the "Natural" way. Need to get X system running instead of VNC.  Thanks to @Milliways